Why is the GD extension for PHP not enabled under Apache but enabled via command line?
I am using Termux (a Debian Linux like environment under Android).

Apache: 2.4.62
PHP: 8.3.10

After updating PHP from 8.3.8 to 8.3.10 the gd extension was lost. The developers provided a 'fix' which I installed, and it did, but only under command line PHP.
$ php -i | grep -i --color gd
Configure Command =>  '/home/builder/.termux-build/php/src/configure'  '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--libdir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-rpath-hack' '--host=aarch64-linux-android' 'ac_cv_func_res_nsearch=no' 'ac_cv_phpdbg_userfaultfd_writefault=no' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromPng=yes' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromAvif=yes' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromWebp=yes' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromJpeg=yes' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromBmp=yes' 'php_cv_lib_gd_gdImageCreateFromTga=yes' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-sockets' '--mandir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/man' '--with-bz2=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-config-file-path=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/php' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/php/conf.d' '--with-curl=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-ldap=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-openssl=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-readline=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-sodium=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-iconv-dir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-pgsql=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-mysql-sock=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/mysqld.sock' '--with-apxs2=/home/builder/.termux-build/php/tmp/apxs-wrapper.sh' '--with-iconv=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--enable-fpm' '--enable-gd=shared,/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--with-external-gd' '--with-external-pcre' '--with-zip' '--with-xsl' '--with-gmp' '--with-ffi' '--with-tidy=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr' '--enable-intl' '--sbindir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin' '--disable-nls' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--libexecdir=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec' 'host_alias=aarch64-linux-android' 'PKG_CONFIG=/home/builder/.termux-build/_cache/android-r27-api-24-v1/bin/pkg-config' 'PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/pkgconfig' 'CPP=aarch64-linux-android-cpp'
Additional .ini files parsed => /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/php/conf.d/gd.ini
gd
GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.3.3
GD library Version => 2.3.3
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => On => On
LOGDIR => /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/log
$_SERVER['LOGDIR'] => /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/var/log

And php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -n gd also shows that gd is installed, but when making a file phpinfo.php in the Apache root folder with the contents <?php phpinfo(); does NOT show gd and websites using gd also fail.
What can be the cause here?

I found the answer on a Termux GitHub issue page. Basically, what you're supposed to do is type in patchelf --add-needed libphp.so $PREFIX/lib/php/gd.so.
However, do note that doing this would mean that php -m in command line would no longer load gd.
Am sidetracking here quite a lot, but this patchelf method should also work for other extensions that don't load properly in Apache, just substitute gd.so with your extension. (I used this method to get luasandbox.so working properly as it's the only way I'm aware of to get Lua working on Mediawiki without root).
